# Correctly merging and pushing with Tortoisegit?

Tags: git, github, merge, tortoisegit

I am new to git, so am a bit confused about merging and pushing. For a normal branch, I simply commit and push, buts lets say I've merged changes from branch1 to master, and now I want to push master, what will be the sequence? Should I just merge and then push or merge, commit and push?

Another confusing thing is that when I merge and push, although changes do appear in the github repository, as seen by logging into github, Tortoisegit doesn't really say anything about those changes. I mean it doesn't say how many files were modified and such. Why is that so?

Comment: i would highly suggest to you leave tortoise ASAP once this tool abstract so much of the git behavior that sometimes becomes painful to do/understand what its doing. use this guy to understand git properly https://try.github.io/ and here https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis/ you can find better GUIs, i suggest personally SmartGit

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. You are right, TortoiseGit is a bit too abstract.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you merge, you would not need to commit again. The merged files were already committed on your branch1. After you merge into master you can just push. So the order looks like this:

```
branch1 -> make changes

branch1 -> stage changes

branch1 -> commit changes

master -> merge branch1

master -> resolve any conflicts, if necessary

master -> push to remote
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks.